# Coordinates of a point - ios-charts [Swift]

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I searched in the library for two days and unfortunately I'm not able to find out how to get the space between two data in px. My `linechartview` is contained in a `UIScrollView` and the aim is to get the value of the `linechartview` point which is located in the center of `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, it has a transfomer to convert data value to px value like:

```
position.x = CGFloat(i) // index on x axis, like 0,1,2
position.y = 0.0
position = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(position, valueToPixelMatrix)
```

Above code is taken from `internal func drawLabels`, at which you should take a look

After this position will be the px. value on the screen. You just need to figure out how you get it and pass to your other functions, like using a delegate

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still blur for me.

Comment: Im sorry I was editing my answer, in order to get the valueToPiexelMatrix I used : let valueToPixelMatrix =  self.lineChartView.getTransformer(ChartYAxis.AxisDependency.Right).valueToPixelMatrix . Is it correct ?

Comment: look at the parameter, which Y axis are you using

Comment: what about in swift5. How to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

When using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

You can go by:

```
let yAxis: Double = 1000 // your value on y-Axis
let xAxis: Double = 5 // your value on x-Axis

let pixel: CGPoint = yourChartView.pixelForValues(x: xAxis, y: yAxis, axis: .right)
```

or

```
let yourDataArray = [ChartDataEntry]()
//... some code here for filling in data

//now, get then position
if let lastPosition = yourDataArray.last {
    let point:CGPoint = yourChartView.getPosition(entry lastPosition: lastPosition , axis: .right)
}
```

In addition, you can check https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Source/Charts/Utils/Transformer.swift for using:

```
let valueToPixelMatrix = yourChartView.getTransformer(forAxis: YAxis.AxisDependency.right).valueToPixelMatrix
```